# Memory allocation in Java Card

Tags: java, arrays, memory, javacard

I have a Java Card smart card and I want to assess the available EEPROM.

To do it, I use the function `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)`.
As the return statment of this function is a `short`, without allocating any data, I get the value `0x7FFF`. To solve this problem, I create `byte` arrays this way: `new byte[(short) 0x7FFF]` to deduce the available persistant memory.

If I create two arrays:

```
arr1 = new byte[(short) 0x7FFF];
arr2 = new byte[(short) 0x7FFF];
```

Then it rests `0x1144` bytes of available memory according to `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)`. So if I sum, it means that there is 32767*2 + 4420 = 69954 bytes available.

But when I change the size of my arrays:

```
arr1 = new byte[(short) 0x7FFF];
arr2 = new byte[(short) 0x6FFF];
```

then it rests `0x2244` bytes of available memory. So if I sum, it means that there is 70210 bytes available.

Another example:
With

```
arr1 = new byte[(short) 0x7FFF];
arr2 = new byte[(short) 0x5FFF];
```

it rests 0x3344 bytes of available memory. So if I sum it means that there is  70466 bytes available.

Even if it's negligible, **why these differences?** (70210 differs from 70466).

In the same way, I want to test how many `AESKey` I can allocate in one applet. So I try to find the available memory as I described before but with `AESKey` arrays.

With the same card, when I create an AESKey array this way:

```
arr = new AESKey[(short) 0x03E8];
for (short i = 0x0000; i < 0x03E8; i++) {
  arr[i] = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES,  KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_256, false);
}
```

So I create an array of a thousand 256 bits `AESKey`. I thought that it would take 32Ko, but the method `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)` indicates that there is `0x0022` bytes available. Why this result?

If I test with half keys (e.g 500):

```
arr = new AESKey[(short) 0x01F4];
for (short i = 0x0000; i < 0x01F4; i++) {
   arr[i] = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES,  KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_256, false);
}
```

the method `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)` indicates that there is `0x55EE` (21998) bytes available: I definitely don't see the relation with the case when I create 1000 keys if the available EEPROM is about 70Ko like I explained at the beginning...

**Could someone describe in detail how the memory is allocated in Java Card to explain the results cited above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons for this:

- there is object allocation overhead;
- there may be overhead with regards to aligning data;
- there may be overhead with regards to memory fragmentation;
- for keys, there may be overhead to keep them secure.

All these issues will reduce the amount of memory available to you. In that regard you should see `getAvailableMemory` as a *rough indication* of the *maximum amount* of memory available.

How much overhead is required depends on the Java Card runtime.

Comment: Strangely, by experimentation, it seems that on my smart card, an object `AESKey` (of 256 bits) occupates approximately 90 bytes (almost three times the size of the key!) in EEPROM. I found it by allocating `AESKey`arrays and calling the function `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)`. I guess this value varies according to smart card manufacturers?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for a short answer:
Java Card isn't to clever storing arrays / it needs additional data. So if you fill up a byte array with **x** bytes to get under the 0x7FFF treshhold the array will internally need more than **x** bytes to store the data and therefore you have a difference that you noticed.

If you are working with JCOP cards you can circumvent the problem by using `UtilX.getAvailableMemory()`.

For a little more knowledge read this:
http://ruimtools.com/doc.php?doc=jc_best on the point reducing EEPROM consumption (however some parts are outdated)